# Trying to "transform: rotate()" a <circle> element using styled-components

Tags: css, svg, rotation, css-transforms, styled-components

**CodeSandbox with example:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-surf-l7m0x

I'm trying to rotate 180º a `circle` element inside an SVG. I'm being able to do it with the regular `<circle>` tag, but I'm not being able to do it with the styled component `styled.circle`

```
LS.Svg_SVG = styled.svg`
  border: 1px dotted silver;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
`;

LS.Circle_CIRCLE = styled.circle`
  stroke-dasharray: 289.0272;
  stroke-dashoffset: -144.5136;
  transform: rotate(180 50 50);             /* <------------ IT DOES NOT WORK */
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <LS.Container_DIV>
        <LS.Svg_SVG viewBox="100 100">
          <circle                            /* USING REGULAR <circle> */
            cx="50"
            cy="50"
            r="46"
            stroke="black"
            strokeWidth="8px"
            fill="none"
            strokeDasharray="289.0272"
            strokeDashoffset="-144.5136"
            transform="rotate(180 50 50)"   /* <----------------- IT WORKS */
          />
        </LS.Svg_SVG>
      </LS.Container_DIV>
      <LS.Container_DIV>
        <LS.Svg_SVG viewBox="100 100">
          <LS.Circle_CIRCLE                 /* USING STYLED COMPONENTS */
            cx="50"
            cy="50"
            r="46"
            stroke="black"
            strokeWidth="8px"
            fill="none"
          />
        </LS.Svg_SVG>
      </LS.Container_DIV>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

The result I'm getting:

[image]

They both should be the same. The first one is rotated (using regular `<circle>`). The second one is not rotated (using `styled-components`). Even though I'm setting `transform: rotate(-180 50 50);` in the styled component.

Comment: In CSS you should try `transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: center center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In CSS, units are required (ie. 180deg, 50px)
2. The SVG-specific version of rotate: `rotate(angle, cx, cy)`, is not supported in the CSS version of `transform`. You'll need to use `transform-origin`.

   ```
   LS.Circle_CIRCLE = styled.circle`
     stroke-dasharray: 289.0272;
     stroke-dashoffset: -144.5136;
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     transform-origin: 50px 50px;
   `;
   ```

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I had no idea about that.